# iphone capturing images while recording with audio queue service

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a audio recording program, which is implemented using audio queue service. It captured the audio data by

```
void AudioOutputCallback(void* inUserData,
             AudioQueueRef outAQ,
             AudioQueueBufferRef outBuffer)
```

method. But I the goal is capturing images while recording the audio file. Then I integrated the UIImagePickerController in the same ViewController to start the image capturing process.

```
-(IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

But the problem is when I fired the captureImage method, the sound recording process is stop . 
Please explain me, whether this is a possible task or not. Is there any other ways to achieve this goal.